# How to get full path of command launched on LSF

Tags: linux, lsf

A user has launched a job on LSF with bsub. From jobId, I can know which command has been executed, but cannot determine full path of that command

```
Job <270090>, User <abhkumar>, Project <default>, 
Interactive pseudo-terminal mode, Command <virtuoso>
```

Is there a way to find it? or PATH variable with that command?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do it. The PATH variable is captured in the submission environment and then set in the job's execution environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something. But its a bit messy.

```
[mclosson@host ~]$ bjobs -l 806

Job <806>, User <mclosson>, Project <default>, Status <RUN>, Queue <normal>, Co
                 mmand <sleep 100000>, Share group charged </mclosson>
Thu Jul  7 15:58:18: Submitted from host <host>, CWD <$HOME>;
Thu Jul  7 15:58:19: Started 1 Task(s) on Host(s) <host>, Allocated 1 Slot(s
                 ) on Host(s) <host>, Execution Home </home/mclosson>, E
                 xecution CWD </home/mclosson>;
Thu Jul  7 15:58:20: Resource usage collected.
                 MEM: 5 Mbytes;  SWAP: 0 Mbytes;  NTHREAD: 4
                 PGID: 11125;  PIDs: 11125 11127 **11129** 


[mclosson@host ~]$ bjobs -o pids 806
PIDS
11125,11127,**11129**


[mclosson@host ~]$ ls -l /proc/**11129**/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mclosson lsf 0 Jul  7 15:59 /proc/11129/exe -> /bin/sleep
```

Its messy because parsing out the job PID from `bjobs -l` is messy.  Parsing `bjobs -o pids` is easier.  The command is probably always the third pid.  The first one is the job res, the second is the job script.  If the command launches other commands, then those pids will appear as well.  I doubt that the order of the pids is guaranteed to not change due to interaction with various LSF features (e.g., cgroups, pim, blaunch). So caveat emptor.

Its also messy because you'll have to `ssh` to the execution host and check the proc filesystem.  And only root or the job execution user can access /proc for that specific process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to isolate what you want:

`bjobs -o 'command' [job_ID]`

See the section in the bsub manpage with:

`bjobs -o "field_name[:[-][output_width]] ...  [delimiter='character']"`

Table 1 contains all the possible output fields you can query.

If you use `-noheader` you can eliminate all output except the field you want.